# Missing debug symbols in statically linked binary

Tags: haskell, gdb, ghc, cabal, haskell-stack

I'm building statically linked binary using stack and I try to add debug symbols to it (following: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/debug-info.html). However GDB reports: `no debugging symbols found`.

What am I missing?

I've added to the `ghc-options` in the [`.cabal` file](https://github.com/carbolymer/haskell-missing-debug-symbols/blob/master/nodebug.cabal): `-g -rtsopts` and to the `ld-options`: `-static`. I am building using stack with the following command:

```
stack install \
    --install-ghc \
    --split-objs \
    --ghc-options="-fPIC -fllvm -pgmlo opt -pgmlc llc"
```

GDB is invoked as follows: `gdb --args nodebug-exe +RTS -V0`

GHC 8.2.1

Whole source code is here: https://github.com/carbolymer/haskell-missing-debug-symbols

Comment: Maybe add --no-strip? `--no-strip: Disable DWARF debugging symbol stripping in libraries, executables, etc. for all expressions`

Comment: @Zpalmtree, That's right. I should've looked into `stack install --help`... You can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`--no-strip` prevents debugging information being removed in the stack build.

From the [documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#dwarf):

> stack now supports debugging and profiling with DWARF information,
>   using the --no-strip, --no-library-stripping, and
>   --no-executable-stripping flags to disable the default behavior of removing such information from compiled libraries and executables.